# recursively replace only one value in python dictionary

Tags: python, json, recursion

I have a dict issued from a json file and I wish to recursively replace only the first occurrence of a value in the dictionary.
So far, I have written a function that replaces all values (ok, I know I am reinventing the wheel):

```
def recursive_replace(dictionary, old_value, new_value):
    if type(dictionary)==dict:
        for k in sorted(dictionary.keys()):
            if dictionary[k] == old_value:
                dictionary[k]= new_value
            elif type(dictionary[k]) in [dict, list]:
                recursive_replace(dictionary[k], old_value, new_value)
    elif type(dictionary)==list:
        for d in dictionary:
            recursive_replace(d, old_value, new_value)
    return dictionary
```

For example, for the dictionary

```
d = {'a':[{'gg':'a'}, {'b':{'a':'gg'}, 'c':'gg'}], 'b':'gg', 'c':{'a':[{'d':'gg'}, {'f':'gg'}]}}
```

calling the function like this:

```
res = recursive_replace(d, 'gg', 'hh')
```

prints

```
{'b': 'hh', 'c': {'a': [{'d': 'hh'}, {'f': 'hh'}]}, 'a': [{'gg': 'a'}, {'d': {'a': 'hh'}, 'c': 'hh'}]}
```

as expected.
What I wish to do is to replace only the first occurrence of the 'gg' value (to ensure which one is the first, keys are sorted). So in this case for example, the fist value to be replaced is the one that I replaced by capital letters:

```
d = {'a':[{'gg':'a'}, {'d':{'a':'gg'}, 'c':'GG'}], 'b':'gg', 'c':{'a':[{'d':'gg'}, {'f':'gg'}]}}
```

The idea behind this is to use the function that replaces only one to replace, by iterating, several values. 
Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance,
M

EDIT : I came up with a solution that seems to work as wanted:

```
def recursive_replace_one(dictionary, old_value, new_value, found):
    if type(dictionary)==dict:
        for k in sorted(dictionary.keys()):
            if not found:
                if dictionary[k] == old_value:
                    dictionary[k]= new_value
                    found = True
                    break
                elif type(dictionary[k]) in [dict, list]:
                    dic, found = recursive_replace_one(dictionary[k], old_value, new_value, True)
    elif type(dictionary)==list:
        for d in dictionary:
            if not found:
                dic, found = recursive_replace_one(d, old_value, new_value, False)
    return dictionary, found
```

It seems rather ugly, thought.
Any suggestions on how to improve this ?

Comment: Can you just add "break" after you replace the value?

Comment: Break won't work correctly if the first occurrence is in a nested dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flag to mark whether or not an update has already taken place:

```
def replace(d, old, new, flag=False):
  _d = {} 
  for a, b in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:isinstance(x[-1], (list, dict))):
    if b == old and not flag:
      _d[a] = new
      flag = True
    else:
      if not isinstance(b, (list, dict)):
        _d[a] = b
      else:
         _d[a] = replace(b, old, new, flag) if isinstance(b, dict) else [replace(i, old, new, flag) for i in b]
  return _d

data = {'a':[{'gg':'a'}, {'b':{'a':'gg'}, 'c':'gg'}], 'b':'gg', 'c':{'a':[{'d':'gg'}, {'f':'gg'}]}} 
print(replace(data, 'gg', 'hh'))
```

Output:

```
{'b': 'hh', 'a': [{'gg': 'a'}, {'c': 'gg', 'b': {'a': 'gg'}}], 'c': {'a': [{'d': 'gg'}, {'f': 'gg'}]}}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what my 'boolean' variable does